# URL parameters and post body in the same Apache httpclient request?

Tags: java, apache, post, get, httpclient

I usually use this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);  
... 
HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
```

Is it possible to pass parameters in a combination of GET and POST in the same request?
I mean some parameters might be pretty long... and I dont want to use GET, I want POST, but to some I do want the GET.

So?

Comment: This is apache's `HttpClient`, correct?

Comment: Why no? It is seems to be valid code using the Apache HttpClient API.

Comment: GET and POST have slightly different meanings. You shouldn't use one or the other just because the arguments might be too long. See [What is the difference between GET and POST?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html). (GET should only be used for idempotent operations).

Comment: @Guillaume Harry means "no" to the original question, not to mre's comment.

Comment: I read the article (+ wikipedia for "idempotence")... and in the last section it states ~ for large form data use POST. But yes, cant use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET and POST are mutually exclusive, you do one or the other (or HEAD, PUT etc). A request cannot be both.

Comment: *However* you *can* pass parameters in the URL of a POST request. It's not usually a good idea, however.

Answer (score 1):

A single HTTP request, according to the protocol, is either GET or POST. There is no way to construct an HTTP header for both at the same time.

*However*

- A POST request be directed to a URL with *query parameters* (the stuff after the ?) and the server can read them.
- a GET request can have content, and the server can read it.